# In subversive eclipse plugin how do you accept just my changes?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

When I get a conflict, I can do

*override and update, inorder to get incoming changes

How do I get it to accept my changes and ignore the incoming ones ?

"override and commit" actually tries to commit, which I don't want to do at that moment.

with svn commandline client the above is straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Choose `Mark as merged` on the files where you want to use your local version.